Query to display top scores including ties, with inner join
I have a query which shows 'High Scores' in the last week. What I need next is to modify this to give the top 3 high scores but including ties such as:
{2FC28DA7-6CD3-4DC0-8465-98534B8F75AD} Bob  250
{2CF80760-B372-4C3D-8BFD-DBAEF4397442} Bill 123
{77F0C9D1-414B-4ABB-8FC0-D1E88969EA6A} Ben  123
{35F0C921-4443-4A30-8AC1-E3288969E4B3} Baz  101

Here's what I have so far:
SELECT TOP (3) tblAccounts.accountID, tblAccounts.contactName, SUM(MONMWins.Points) As ttlPoints
FROM MONMWins
INNER JOIN tblAccounts
ON MONMWins.accountID = tblAccounts.accountID
WHERE MONMWins.dateAdded > DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
GROUP BY tblAccounts.accountID, tblAccounts.contactName
ORDER BY ttlPoints DESC, tblAccounts.contactName


When you say you want top 3 with ties do you mean you want Bob, Bill and Ben or Bob, Bill, Ben and Baz?

add WITH TIES after TOP (3) and remove ,tblAccounts.contantName from the ORDER BY

Need all 4 or more if necessary. Top 3 points, so people can share 1st, 2nd and 3rd place.

Tried that, it works but i'm probably not expaining it correctly.. So if there's 2 players joint first, 3 joint second and 2 joint third, it would give 7 results. Does that make sense?

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, ensuring you cover edge cases.

That's not TOP that's DENSE_RANK. Effectively Get top 1 row of each group but replace 1 with 3 and DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.

TOP(3) looks at the top three rows. Even if you make this TOP(3) WITH TIES, the DBMS will look at the first three rows and only include more rows when they have the same points sum as the third row.
What you want to do instead is look at the points and rank the rows accordingly. This is done with DENSE_RANK.
WITH
  ranked AS
  (
    SELECT 
      a.accountid, 
      a.contactname, 
      SUM(w.points) As ttlpoints,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(w.points) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM monmwins w
    INNER JOIN tblaccounts a ON a.accountid = w.accountid 
    WHERE w.dateadded > DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
    GROUP BY a.accountid, a.contactname
  )
SELECT accountid, contactname, ttlpoints
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk <= 3
ORDER BY ttlpoints DESC, contactname;

Or a tad more concise:
WITH
  top3 AS
  (
    SELECT TOP(3) WITH TIES
      a.accountid, 
      a.contactname, 
      SUM(w.points) As ttlpoints
    FROM monmwins w
    INNER JOIN tblaccounts a ON a.accountid = w.accountid 
    WHERE w.dateadded > DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
    GROUP BY a.accountid, a.contactname
    ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(w.points) DESC)
  )
SELECT *
FROM top3
ORDER BY ttlpoints DESC, contactname;

Here, TOP(3) works, because we don't base it on an order of points, but on an order of point ranks.
